# Regular Expression: 10 digits with dash on position 3,4 or 5

Tags: regex

Im trying to verify an inputfield with regular expression. The user can enter a 10 digit number which can contain a dash on position 3,4 or 5. When i use only one expression, it works, but I can't get it to work with or-statements.
Offcourse it would be a solution to trim al the dashes, but i would like to do it this way.

Examples which should be allowed

```
0123456789
01-23456789
012-3456789
0123-456789
```

What I think should work

```
(^d{10}$)|
(^d{2}\-d{8}$)|
(^d{3}\-d{7}$)|
(^d{4}\-d{6}$)
```

Comment: what programming language you working in?

Comment: You forgot to escape the `d`s. `d` matches the literal character `d`. To match a digit, use `\d`. Fix that, and your pattern works.

Comment: `^(?:\d{10}|\d{2}-\d{8}|\d{3}-\d{7}|\d{4}-\d{6})$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with a lookahead and alternationn:

```
^(?:\d{10}|(?=[\d-]{11}$)\d{2,4}-\d+)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jaS7Hd/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^(?:`: Start with a non-capturing group

  - `\d{10}`: Match all 10 digits
  - `|`: OR
  - `(?=[\d-]{11}$)`: Make sure total length is 11 including `-`
  - `\d{2,4}-\d+`: Make sure `-` is at 3rd, 4th or 5th positions
- `)$`: End non-capturing group in the end

---

As Revo suggested below a shorter version can be:

```
^(?=(?:-?\d){10}$)\d{2,4}-?\d+$
```

Comment: This is the most readable, short answer. +1. My two cents for a shorter expression `^(?=(?:-?\d){10}$)\d{2,4}-?\d+$`

Comment: Thanks @revo: `^(?=(?:-?\d){10}$)\d{2,4}-?\d+$` is definitely shorter though it takes almost 4 times more steps. But OP should use this shorter version if not using regex on a big set of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern `(?=\d{2,4}-\d{6,8})^[\d-]{11}$`

It uses positive lookahead: `(?=\d{2,4}-\d{6,8})` to assure that what follows is:

`\d{2,4}` - 2 up to 4 digits

`-` - dash literally

`\d{6,8}` - 6 to 8 digits

This assures that you will have dash at 2nd,3rd,4th position.

If this is satisfied, than match: `^` - beginning of a string, `[\d-]{11}` - eleven characters (digits or dash), `$` - end of a string

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FaogMS/3)

**Update**: `(?(?=\d{2,4}-\d{6,8})^[\d-]{11}$|^\d{10}$)`

This uses alternation - if above lookahead is satisfied, it matches digits with dash, if i isn't, then it matches pattern `^\d{10}$`, which is simply match ten digits only.

Comment: Did you use the conditional cluster `(?(...)...` on purpose?

Comment: @revo Yes, in order to match different patterns based on result of lookahead.

Comment: Not even all popular engines support conditionals and we are not aware of what regex flavor OP uses. And here you don't need conditionals at all `(?=\d{2,4}-\d{6,8})^[\d-]{11}$|^\d{10}$` works fine.

Answer (score -1):

You just forgot to put backslashes in front of the d's. This regex should do it:

```
(^\d{10}$)|(^\d{2}\-\d{8}$)|(^\d{3}\-\d{7}$)|(^\d{4}\-\d{6}$)
```

Check out here: https://regex101.com/r/Nyjvfh/2

Comment: Please flag / vote to close questions caused by typos - they're off-topic, and have no chance of being of any value to future readers

Comment: A shorter version of writing the regex would be `(^\d{10}$)|(^\d{2,4}\-\d+$)`

Comment: That would match `0123-4567890123456`

Comment: @CertainPerformance: thx for the input, fixed that: `(^\d{10}$)|(^\d{2,4}\-\d{6,8}$)`

Comment: That will match `01-234567`

Comment: Your second regex should use a lookahead `^\d{10}$|^(?=[\d-]{11}$)\d{2,4}\-\d+$`

Comment: @revo: This is the most elegant version posted here, thank you. this should be the solution in my opinion.

Comment: You could even remove the first side of alternation: `^(?=(\D*\d){10}$)\d{2,4}-?\d+$`